# Initialize button in one fragment but set click on another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have defined the button in FragmentA but I want to set its click on FragmentB. I have used interfaces for that but it causes null pointer exception. Please suggest me some way.

Comment: They'll need to have the same parent activity and then just have the click method you want to call in the activity. Calling one fragment from another is a very bad practice.

Comment: I have two tab layouts into one another so calling fragment from fragment is only choice for me

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: **Don't** do that. Don't try to manipulate one fragment from another fragment. At least use activity for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is very common in Android and can be called inter component communication, where you can trigger event or message from one component to another component.

Though there are many ways to achieve it like using static entities, in your case it will be coded at parent activity because both fragment case see it,   but it is not good practice and have many side effects.

You may consider to use event handler specific libraries such as EventBus, Otto, RxJava and RxAndroid.

As a beginner you may start with EventBus, though personally I like to use Rxjava.